# Terminal claims that grep-command doesn't exist

Tags: macos, terminal

When I use a grep in conjunction with a pipe, like for example `ls -la | grep config`. Then Terminal reports that the grep-command doesn't exist: `-bash:  grep: command not found`.

**What goes wrong here? How can the issue become fixed?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the error message, there seem to be two spaces before `grep`. Most likely you had the <kbd>Opt</kbd> key still pressed when typing a space character.

See the answer to [Terminal gives :command not found, when typing too fast](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282421/terminal-gives-command-not-found-when-typing-too-fast) for more details.